# Segmentation fault (core dumped) with "FILE *pFile;"?

Tags: c, linux

I got "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

and process was interrupted.

Help to fix it please!

suspicious part code here

...

```
FILE *pFile;
char buffer[100];
sprintf(buffer,"/var/www/html/%s.txt",topic);

pFile = fopen(buffer,"w" );
```

This problem may occur in the above
(Did not enter if-else)

```
if( NULL == pFile ){
    _mosquitto_log_printf(NULL, MOSQ_LOG_DEBUG,"open failure" );
}else{
    fwrite(payload,1,sizeof(payload)-1,pFile);
    _mosquitto_log_printf(NULL, MOSQ_LOG_INFO, "File context : %s", payload);
}
fclose(pFile);
```

...

OS Ubuntu 14

Comment: What is `payload`?

Comment: Did you try to use a debugger to see which instruction caused the segfault ?

Comment: If `topic` is long enough, the text you create may not fit in the buffer. Since this looks as if it is on the stack, a buffer overrun would probably corrupt `pFile`, some other variables and perhaps even the return address. IOW: it could be a classical buffer overrun (but without malicious intent). As you said, the problem could occur before you enter the if-else clause.

Comment: Thanks you guys suggests, The problem has been solved, 
pFile maybe an invalid pointer, so fclose(pFile) have to inside the else statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call `fclose` using `pFile` even when it's a null pointer. Calling `fclose` with an invalid pointer (like a null pointer) or a `FILE*` that has already been closed is *undefined*.

Only call `fclose` is the pointer is not `NULL`, i.e. in the `else` clause of your code.